# "Refinable" property not returning from ManagedProperties query to SharePoint Online Search Rest Endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-search

I'm using the PnP Search webparts so I've logged this there as well under https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/issues/3624, but it's actually the Search service that's the issue. I have a mapped property, RefinableDate00, that's populated with birthdays from the User Profile service. I can successfully use the value in a Search query. It doesn't come back in the call to retrieve ManagedProperties though (on the PnP Search Result part, when I click to open the list of available "Selected properties", it doesn't appear). It's the out of the box RefinableDate00 property, so it's of course Searchable, Refineable and Retrievable - am I missing some other configuration?

Comment: Did you try to insert the value `RefinableDate00` in the combobox? (yes, you can edit it)

Comment: AHH! I thought the functionality had gone away (I remember it used to exist), but I was just clicking the wrong place! Thank you!